# traer un solo dato si el dato en un campo en la base de dato es igual al de otro campo en la misma tabla

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Tengo una consulta con PHP que me lista los mails del campo " mail del padre" y "mail de la madre", pero necesito que en la consulta me muestre unicamente una sola vez el mail, en algunos campos el mail del padre es el mismo que está en el campo "mail de la madre" por peticion de ese padre, en ese caso,  si no puedo simplemente borrarlo en un campo asi cuando me liste los mails no me aparezcan dos veces el mail, cada uno correspondiente al campo mail del padre y mail de la madre, como hago para filtrar que si el campo de uno de los dos es igual al otro campo, me traiga solo una vez el mail? dejo el codigo para entender mejor:

```
familia.`Email del padre`
FROM
familia
Inner Join main ON familia.id = main.id_familia
Inner Join academica ON academica.id_alumno = main.id
WHERE
academica.nivel =  'jardin' 

GROUP BY
familia.`Email del padre`
ORDER BY
familia.`Email del padre` ASC";
                    $consulta2="SELECT
familia.`Email de la madre`
FROM
familia
Inner Join main ON familia.id = main.id_familia
Inner Join academica ON academica.id_alumno = main.id
WHERE
academica.nivel =  'jardin'
GROUP BY
familia.`Email de la madre`
ORDER BY
familia.`Email de la madre` ASC";
                    break;
```

Esta consulta me trae esto:

Mailpadre1@gmail.com  
mailmadre1@gmail.com 
padremail@gmail.com 
madremail@gmail.com 
**solotienemaildepadre@gmail.com 

solotienemaildepadre@gmail.com**

```
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
 {
     echo $row['Email del padre'].'<br>';
 }
 $resultado=mysql_query($consulta2);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
 {
     echo $row['Email de la madre'].'<br>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba utilizar 'distinct' para evitar datos repetidos, debe quedarte algo así

```
Select distinct
familia.`Email del padre`
FROM
familia
Inner Join main ON familia.id = main.id_familia
Inner Join academica ON academica.id_alumno = main.id
WHERE
academica.nivel =  'jardin' 

GROUP BY
familia.`Email del padre`
ORDER BY
familia.`Email del padre` ASC";
                    $consulta2="SELECT distinct
familia.`Email de la madre`
FROM
familia
Inner Join main ON familia.id = main.id_familia
Inner Join academica ON academica.id_alumno = main.id
WHERE
academica.nivel =  'jardin'
GROUP BY
familia.`Email de la madre`
ORDER BY
familia.`Email de la madre` ASC";
                    break;
```

Saludos